# I cannot change the TFS workspace

Tags: azure-devops

Where I work we have a TFS 2015 server. I need to get in to Get Latest on a project, which is under a different workspace. However, I cannot change workspaces, no matter what I do.

When I get into VS 2019 (version 16.8.5), without opening any project, I then get into Source Control Explorer. From there I click on the Workspace dropdown. I see the "Workspaces..." in the dropdown, then select the workspace which is associated with the folder I'm trying to get to.

Then nothing happens. In particular, the workspace doesn't change.

If I go to File | Source Control | Advanced | Workspaces... where I can see all the workspaces I have. I select the one I want to in the listbox. I click on the Edit... button.

That opens the Edit Workspace  dialog box, which shows me the working folders, including the one I need. Then I click on the OK button.

Nothing happens. The workspace hasn't changed. I cannot get to our code in TFS, which I need to do. This is a total showstopper.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi, Not get your latest information, are the answers below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues suggested that I get out of Visual Studio, then reboot. This worked. Not saying it will work in all situations, but it is at least worth while giving it a try.

Answer (score 1):

> Change TFS workspace

Connect TFS project and click the button `Source Control Explorer`, at the top of the source control explorer window you should have a toolbar with a few buttons. Somewhere on that toolbar there should be a Workspace dropdown. Just select the workspace you want to use from that dropdown. Then we could change the workspace, check the pic below.

[image]

> If I go to File | Source Control | Advanced | Workspaces...

Since these steps just check the workspace info instead of change worksapce, after you click the OK button, it will back to Manage Workspaces page.

If you still cannot change your workspace from the dropdown list. You could create a new workspace and re-map the TFS code again, it should work.

**Update1**

Thanks for Rod sharing.

Just get out of VS 2019 and reboot it, then it works.

Comment: A colleague suggested that I get out of VS 2019, then reboot. That took care of it. Strange, but whatever floats its boat.

Comment: Hi @Rod, I shared your solution in the answer, you could also share your answer here and mark it as the answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)